# Given a triangular matrix $T$, can we find an upper bound for $\| |T^{-1}||T|\|$?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Given a triangular matrix $T$, can we find an upper bound for $\| |T^{-1}||T|\|$, where $|T| =|[T_{ij}]| = [|T_{ij}|]$ ?

Comment: Beside the condition?

Comment: @user251257 yes

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: @user251257 Any subordinate matrix norm.